# Limit lambda concurrency to 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to control the lambda concurrency, and set the concurrency limit to exactly 1( i.e. only 1 instance of the my lambda should run).
How can i achieve this?

I tried to edit the concurrency in aws management console and set Reserve concurrency to 1 but getting the error `The unreserved account concurrency can't go below 10.`[image]

Comment: Either free up reserved concurrency from other lambdas or request a lambda concurrency limit increase.

Comment: https://repost.aws/questions/QUzGtqXgNdSNCHkmM0qJ2NfA/cannot-set-reserve-concurrency-for-a-lambda-function

Comment: Why is your "Unreserved account concurrency" so low? Have you been assigning amounts to _other_ Lambda functions? Is there a reason for doing so?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein No idea. May be because this is for newly created free-tier account

Comment: This is because it is a new account. You will need to request an increase to go above 100 (min unreserved concurrency). you could request 110. The quota increase is available as part of the Service Quotas directly from your aws console.

Comment: Please note that setting reserved concurrency to 1 will mean that any new events during that time will go straight to a DLQ if you have one set up. See this article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-maximum-concurrency-of-aws-lambda-functions-when-using-amazon-sqs-as-an-event-source/

Answer (score 0):

I raised a quota increase request for concurrency and this solves the problem. My unreserved account concurrency shows 100 and now I can limit my lambda concurrency to 1

Answer (score -1):

as mention in aws documentation for [Configuring reserved concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html):

> You can reserve up to the Unreserved account concurrency value that is
> shown, minus 100 for functions that don't have reserved concurrency.

in your aws account seems the unreserved limit is 10.

You have to open a request to aws support and ask to increase lambda concurrency to a number higher than 10, so you can set reserved concurrency for certain lambda functions in your account.

Comment: I did raise mine to 15, and I still get the same issue. There is only 1 lambda in this account.

Comment: it depand what is your Unreserved account concurrency.
In the question above, it was relevant according to the limitation shown in the error (10 unreserved min).
In my account for example, Unreserved account concurrency=1000
so I can define Reserve concurrency <=900 (according to the docs)

what is your Unreserved account concurrency?
what do you get in the error?